# Java Processing time lapse drawing not working

Tags: java, eclipse, drawing, processing, timelapse

I am making a time lapse visualisation using java and Processing. This code is from Eclipse which I use to help myself since Processing lacks autocomplete. The problem lies in void `PozeniPrezentacijo()` method. The problem I have is that when I do risi() (risi means draw) and then `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)` ten times it freezes for 10 seconds and only shows the output of the last `draw() (risi())`. I have also tried with `Thread.sleep()` but the same happens. It might be hard to debug because you have to import processing libraries to Eclipse. [Link](http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/).

My full code:

```
import g4p_controls.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import de.bezier.data.sql.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import processing.core.*;




public class MyProcessingSketch extends PApplet {





        // Create all the GUI controls. 
        // autogenerated do not edit
    /* =========================================================
     * ====                   WARNING                        ===
     * =========================================================
     * The code in this tab has been generated from the GUI form
     * designer and care should be taken when editing this file.
     * Only add/edit code inside the event handlers i.e. only
     * use lines between the matching comment tags. e.g.

     void myBtnEvents(GButton button) { //_CODE_:button1:12356:
         // It is safe to enter your event code here  
     } //_CODE_:button1:12356:

     * Do not rename this tab!
     * =========================================================
     */

        public void handleSliderEvents(GSlider slider, GEvent event) {
          println("integer value:" + slider1.getValueI() + " float value:" + slider1.getValueF());

          if(slider1.getValueI() == 1810){NastaviRadije(slovar1);
          risi();}

          else if(slider1.getValueI() == 1820){NastaviRadije(slovar2);
          risi();}

          else if(slider1.getValueI() == 1830){NastaviRadije(slovar3);
          risi();}

          else if(slider1.getValueI() == 1840){NastaviRadije(slovar4);
          risi();}

          else if(slider1.getValueI() == 1850){NastaviRadije(slovar5);
          risi();}

          else if(slider1.getValueI() == 1860){NastaviRadije(slovar6);
          risi();}

          else if(slider1.getValueI() == 1870){NastaviRadije(slovar7);
          risi();}

          else if(slider1.getValueI() == 1880){NastaviRadije(slovar8);
          risi();}

          else if(slider1.getValueI() == 1890){NastaviRadije(slovar9);
          risi();}

          else if(slider1.getValueI() == 1900){NastaviRadije(slovar2);
          risi();}

        }



    public void button1_click1(GButton source, GEvent event) { //_CODE_:button1:393804:
      NastaviBarve();
      risi();
    } //_CODE_:button1:393804:

    public void button2_click1(GButton source, GEvent event) throws Exception { //_CODE_:button1:393804:
      PozeniPrezentacijo();

    }



    // Create all the GUI controls. 
    // autogenerated do not edit
    public void createGUI(){
      G4P.messagesEnabled(false);
      G4P.setGlobalColorScheme(GCScheme.BLUE_SCHEME);
      G4P.setCursor(ARROW);
      if(frame != null)
        frame.setTitle("Sketch Window");
      sketchPad1 = new GSketchPad(this, 18, 13, 762, 459);
      sketchPad1.setOpaque(true);
      label1 = new GLabel(this, 220, 270, 240, 50);
      label1.setText("Drzava1");
      label1.setOpaque(false);
      label2 = new GLabel(this, 620, 300, 240, 50);
      label2.setText("Drzava2");
      label2.setOpaque(false);
      label3 = new GLabel(this, 790, 110, 240, 50);
      label3.setText("Drzava3");
      label3.setOpaque(false);
      label4 = new GLabel(this, 860, 300, 240, 50);
      label4.setText("Drzava4");
      label4.setOpaque(false);
      label5 = new GLabel(this, 1030, 200, 240, 50);
      label5.setText("Drzava5");
      label5.setOpaque(false);
      label6 = new GLabel(this, 220, 580, 240, 50);
      label6.setText("Drzava6");
      label6.setOpaque(false);
      label7 = new GLabel(this, 470, 550, 240, 50);
      label7.setText("Drzava7");
      label7.setOpaque(false);
      label8 = new GLabel(this, 590, 500, 240, 50);
      label8.setText("Drzava8");
      label8.setOpaque(false);
      label9 = new GLabel(this, 710, 550, 240, 50);
      label9.setText("Drzava9");
      label9.setOpaque(false);
      label10 = new GLabel(this, 830, 500, 240, 50);
      label10.setText("Drzava10");
      label10.setOpaque(false);
      //label11 = new GLabel(this, 430, 20, 300, 30);
      //label11.setText("Vizualizacija prikazuje število avtoric iz posamezne države po desetletjih");
      //label11.setOpaque(false);
      slider1 = new GSlider(this, 123, 620, 983, 61, (float) 10.0);
      slider1.setShowValue(true);
      slider1.setShowLimits(true);
      slider1.setLimits(1810, 1810, 1900);
      slider1.setNbrTicks(10);
      slider1.setStickToTicks(true);
      slider1.setShowTicks(true);
      slider1.setNumberFormat(G4P.DECIMAL, 2);
      slider1.setOpaque(false);
      slider1.addEventHandler(this, "handleSliderEvents");
      button1 = new GButton(this, 1150, 600, 80, 30);
      button1.setText("Spremeni barve");
      button1.addEventHandler(this, "button1_click1");
      button2 = new GButton(this, 1150, 650, 120, 30);
      button2.setText("Poženi predstavitev");
      button2.addEventHandler(this, "button2_click1");

    }

    // Variable declarations 
    // autogenerated do not edit
    GSketchPad sketchPad1; 
    GLabel label1; 
    GLabel label2; 
    GLabel label3; 
    GLabel label4; 
    GLabel label5; 
    GLabel label6; 
    GLabel label7; 
    GLabel label8; 
    GLabel label9; 
    GLabel label10; 
    GLabel label11; 
    GLabel label12; 
    GSlider slider1; 
    GButton button1; 
    GButton button2; 



    MySQL msql;
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar3 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar4 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar5 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar6 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar7 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar8 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar9 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> slovar10 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    Integer radij1, radij2, radij3, radij4, radij5, radij6, radij7, radij8, radij9, radij10;
    String drzava1, drzava2,drzava3, drzava4, drzava5, drzava6, drzava7, drzava8, drzava9, drzava10;
    PFont f;

    //color c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10;
    //colorMode(RGB,255);
    int c1 = color(255,0,0);
        int c2 = color(255,128,0);
        int c3 = color(255,255,0);
        int c4 = color(128,255,0);
        int c5 = color(0,255,0);
        int c6 = color(0,255,128);
        int c7 = color(0,255,255);
        int c8 = color(0,128,255);
        int c9 = color(0,0,255);
        int c10 = color(127,0,255);

    public void setup() {
        size(1280, 720);
        f = createFont("Arial",16,true);


        createGUI();

        String user = "studentgo";
        String pass = "yP6YZcbSacFcCpuq";

            String database = "studentgo";
            // imena polj v bazi: ime, naslov, leto_izdaje, drzava_izdaje, receptor, spol, tip, leto_recepcije, drzava_recepcije
            msql = new MySQL( this, "delphi.fri.uni-lj.si:3306", database, user, pass );




            if (msql.connect()) {//Drzave za obdobje 1800 do 1900;

                msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1800 AND leto_izdaje<1810 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                            slovar1.put(beseda, pravoSt);

                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }

                  msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1810 AND leto_izdaje<1820 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {

                            slovar2.put(beseda, pravoSt);
                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }

                  msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1820 AND leto_izdaje<1830 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {

                            slovar3.put(beseda, pravoSt);

                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }

                  msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1830 AND leto_izdaje<1840 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {

                            slovar4.put(beseda, pravoSt);

                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }

                  msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1840 AND leto_izdaje<1850 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {

                            slovar5.put(beseda, pravoSt);

                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }

                  msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1850 AND leto_izdaje<1860 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {

                            slovar6.put(beseda, pravoSt);

                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }

                  msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1860 AND leto_izdaje<1870 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {

                            slovar7.put(beseda, pravoSt);

                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }

                  msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1870 AND leto_izdaje<1880 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {

                            slovar8.put(beseda, pravoSt);

                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }

                  msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1880 AND leto_izdaje<1890 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {

                            slovar9.put(beseda, pravoSt);

                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }

                msql.query("SELECT drzava_izdaje, count(drzava_izdaje) s FROM avtorice where leto_izdaje>1890 AND leto_izdaje<1900 group by drzava_izdaje");
                while (msql.next()) {

                    String stevilo = msql.getString("s");
                    int pravoSt = Integer.parseInt(stevilo);
                    String beseda = msql.getString("drzava_izdaje");
                    if (beseda.contains("unknown / not relevant")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {

                            slovar10.put(beseda, pravoSt);

                    }
                    //print(beseda +"," + pravoSt +"\n");

                  }



              }
            else {
                // connection failed !
            }
      NastaviRadije(slovar1);
      risi();

    }//konec setup



    public void draw() {
      //background(255, 255, 255);

    }

    void NastaviBarve(){
        c1 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        c2 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        c3 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        c4 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        c5 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        c6 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        c7 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        c8 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        c9 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        c10 = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));

    }

    void NastaviRadije(HashMap slovar){
      ArrayList<Integer> stevila = new ArrayList<Integer>(slovar.values());
      Collections.sort(stevila);
      Collections.reverse(stevila);
      radij1 = stevila.get(0);
      radij2 = stevila.get(1);
      radij3 = stevila.get(2);
      radij4 = stevila.get(3);
      radij5 = stevila.get(4);
      radij6 = stevila.get(5);
      radij7 = stevila.get(6);
      radij8 = stevila.get(7);
      radij9 = stevila.get(8);
      radij10 = stevila.get(9);
      NastaviDrzave(slovar);

      }

    void NastaviDrzave(HashMap slovar){
      ArrayList<String> drzave = new ArrayList<String>(slovar.keySet());

      for( String drzava : drzave){
        Integer radij = (Integer) slovar.get(drzava);
        if(radij == radij1) {drzava1 = drzava;}
        else if(radij == radij2) {drzava2 = drzava;}
        else if(radij == radij3) {drzava3 = drzava;}
        else if(radij == radij4) {drzava4 = drzava;}
        else if(radij == radij5) {drzava5 = drzava;}
        else if(radij == radij6) {drzava6 = drzava;}
        else if(radij == radij7) {drzava7 = drzava;}
        else if(radij == radij8) {drzava8 = drzava;}
        else if(radij == radij9) {drzava9 = drzava;}
        else if(radij == radij10) {drzava10 = drzava;}
        else continue;
      }
    }



    void risi(){

        background(255, 255, 255);
        fill(254,0,0);
        textFont(f,30);        
        textAlign(LEFT); 
        text("Vizualizacija prikazuje število avtoric iz posamezne države po desetletjih",200,30);
        fill(0,0,0);
        textFont(f,20);        
        textAlign(LEFT); 
        text("Premakni drsnik za začetek.",950,80);
        textFont(f,20);        
        textAlign(LEFT); 
        text("Pritisni gumb za spremembo barv.",950,100);
        ellipseMode(CENTER);
        fill(c1);
        ellipse(220,270,radij1,radij1);
        label1.setText(drzava1+" ("+radij1.toString()+")");
        label1.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label1.setTextBold();
        fill(c2);
        ellipse(620,300,radij2,radij2);
        label2.setText(drzava2+" ("+radij2.toString()+")");
        label2.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label2.setTextBold();
        fill(c3);
        ellipse(790,110,radij3,radij3);
        label3.setText(drzava3+" ("+radij3.toString()+")");
        label3.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label3.setTextBold();
        fill(c4);
        ellipse(860,300,radij4,radij4);
        label4.setText(drzava4+" ("+radij4.toString()+")");
        label4.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label4.setTextBold();
        fill(c5);
        ellipse(1030,200,radij5,radij5);
        label5.setText(drzava5+" ("+radij5.toString()+")");
        label5.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label5.setTextBold();
        fill(c6);
        ellipse(220,580,radij6,radij6);
        label6.setText(drzava6+" ("+radij6.toString()+")");
        label6.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label6.setTextBold();
        fill(c7);
        ellipse(470,550,radij7,radij7);
        label7.setText(drzava7+" ("+radij7.toString()+")");
        label7.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label7.setTextBold();
        fill(c8);
        ellipse(590,500,radij8,radij8);
        label8.setText(drzava8+" ("+radij8.toString()+")");
        label8.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label8.setTextBold();
        fill(c9);
        ellipse(710,550,radij9,radij9);
        label9.setText(drzava9+" ("+radij9.toString()+")");
        label9.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label9.setTextBold();
        fill(c10);
        ellipse(830,500,radij10,radij10);
        label10.setText(drzava10+" ("+radij10.toString()+")");
        label10.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        label10.setTextBold();

    }

    void PozeniPrezentacijo() throws Exception{
        slider1.setValue(1810);
        risi();
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        slider1.setValue(1820);
        risi();
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        slider1.setValue(1830);
        risi();
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        slider1.setValue(1840);
        risi();
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        slider1.setValue(1850);
        risi();
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        slider1.setValue(1860);
        risi();
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        slider1.setValue(1870);
        risi();
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        slider1.setValue(1880);
        risi();
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        slider1.setValue(1890);
        risi();
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        slider1.setValue(1900);
        risi();
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are going to use Processing and its libraries you have to play by its rules.. Specifically G4P' UI depends on void draw() meaning you can't call noLoop and refresh the screen at will... And it also seems Processing's redraw() doesnt actually call draw() directly, but only sets a flag that the window needs to be repainted. The general idea being here that you have to design around Processing's draw() loop... So I suggest something like this:

Instead of actually calling the capture method trigger a chain of events that will, in each draw() display different information according to the sequence. Thus:

to trigger the event:

```
public void button2_click1(GButton source, GEvent event) throws Exception { //_CODE_:button1:393804:
  val = 1810;
}
```

draw method:

```
public void draw() {
  PozeniPrezentacijo();
}
```

and the actual method:

```
int val = 1901;
void PozeniPrezentacijo() {
  if (val < 1901 && frameCount%30 == 0) {
    slider1.setValue(val);
    risi();
    val+=10;
  }
}
```

the frameCount%30 = 0 allows you to only run this one every 30 frames